# How to take back flags?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed

Recently, I flagged [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161168/what-is-a-viable-build-for-teemo-vs-teemo/214573#214573) as 'Not an answer'.

Now, after looking at it a couple of times, I have realized that this *is* an answer, just it is extremely badly written and needs editing.

So my question is: **how do I take back a flag that I have put on a question/answer? If this is not possible, could this feature be implemented?**

The main reason why I want to take it back is so that the moderator queue is shorter. Also, to reduce the number of declined flags on my account.

**EDIT**: It turned out my flag was deemed helpful after all. I would still like an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To retract a flag, simply click the flag button again, then click the "retract flag" button:

[image]

You will then get the message "Your flag has been retracted" near the flag button.

[image]

It is worth noting that self-removed flags still show up in your flagging history. However, they are in a category called "retracted" rather than "declined."

Answer (score 3):

You cannot take back flags. This is by design: flagging should be something done with careful consideration.

Everybody, however, makes mistakes. A declined flag is nothing to worry about at all.

Comment: might wanna update since you can retract flags now